# i need to sum sale and QTy for each DEP between to dates in 2 different column

Tags: sql

```
  Date      Dep     Sales      Qty
01/07/2018  0103    13,618     459
20/08/2018  0325    237        13
01/01/2018  0318    2,121      39 
30/06/2018  0105    19,886    1,586
01/07/2019  0103    13,618     459
01/04/2019  0325    237        13
01/01/2020  0318    2,121      39
30/06/2020  0105    19,886    1,586
```

i need to sum sale and QTy for each DEP 
when date is between (01/07/2018 to 30/06/2019) on a column (18)
and date is between (01/07/2019 to 30/06/2020)on anther a column (19)

```
Dep     Sales 18    Sales 19    Qty 18    Qty 19
0103    13,618       13,618       459      459
0325    237           237         13       13
0318    2,121        2,121        39       39
0105    19,886      19,886      1,586     1,586
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select dep,
       sum(case when date >= '2018-01-01' and date < '2019-01-01' then sales else 0 end) as sales_2018,
       sum(case when date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01' then sales else 0 end) as sales_2019,
       sum(case when date >= '2018-01-01' and date < '2019-01-01' then qty else 0 end) as qty_2018,
       sum(case when date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01' then qty else 0 end) as qty_2019
from t
group by dep;
```

Date operations are notoriously database-dependent.  Something like this should work on whatever database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your help i got it